# I want to get device country name so I am using react-native localize package but it is giving united states but I am in india

Tags: react-native, react-native-localize

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import LogInviaPhone from '../Screens/LogInviaPhone';
import LogInviaEmail from '../Screens/LogInviaEmail';
import OTPScreen from '../Screens/OTPScreen';
import OTPScreenEmail from '../Screens/OTPScreenEmail';
import HomeScreen from '../Screens/HomeScreen';
import * as RNLocalize from 'react-native-localize';
import ISO3166 from 'iso-3166-1-alpha-2';

const Stack=createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function Navigation() {

  const [country,setCountry]=useState(null);

  useEffect(()=>{
    const fetchCountry=async()=>{
      try{
        const locales = RNLocalize.getLocales();
        const countryCode = locales[0]?.countryCode; 
        const countryName = ISO3166.getCountry(countryCode);
        setCountry(countryName);
      }catch(error){
        console.log('Error fetching country:', error);
      }
    }
    fetchCountry();
  },[]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Country ",country); // Log the country name whenever it changes
  }, [country]);

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name='Phone Login' component={LogInviaPhone} options={{
          headerShown:false
        }}/>
        <Stack.Screen name='Email Login' component={LogInviaEmail} options={{
          headerShown:false
        }}/>
        <Stack.Screen name='OTP Phone' component={OTPScreen} options={{
          headerShown:false
        }}/>
        <Stack.Screen name='OTP Email' component={OTPScreenEmail} options={{
          headerShown:false
        }}/>
        <Stack.Screen name='Home' component={HomeScreen} options={{
          headerShown:false
        }}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

I am getting united states in result but I am in india so it is not giving appropriate result what should I do. Is there any other package for this purpose. I am making a react native app where when user open the app first he has to login and if he is from india then app will open login with phone number and if he is from outside of india then app will open login with email.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of **[react-native-localize](https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-localize?tab=readme-ov-file#getcountry)** the method get the country is based on device locales not on device position, so, if you set English-US, you will get US as Country Code.

To get the current device location, you have two options, either get the **IP Address** and use API like [ipapi.co](http://ip-api.com/) or get the country code based on the GeoLocation of device.
**Method One (using IP Address):**
Install [react-native-network-info](https://github.com/pusherman/react-native-network-info) and [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) create a function to get IP Address and get the country code:\

```
import {NetworkInfo} from 'react-native-network-info';

async function getCountryCode(){
    let countryCode;
    const ipAddress = await NetworkInfo.getIPV4Address();
    const response = await axios.get(`http://ip-api.com/json/${ipAddress}`);
    const data = response.data;
    if(data?.status === 'success'){
       countryCode = data?.countryCode
    }
   return countryCode
}
```

**Method Two:**
This will require to get the current location of the user, get it's **Latitude** and **Longitude** and do some **Reverse GeoCoding**

Also give this [react-native-device-country](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-country) a try it will get the device country based on the **SIM Card** (telephony) settings.

Comment: I tried  react-native-network-info and axios but I am getting this api response - 
 LOG  API Response: {"message": "private range", "query": "192.168.32.217", "status": "fail"}  
@anwersolangi

Comment: @MuskanVerma sorry about that, it looks like the getIPAddress, get the local API of the device, however, using getIPV4Address function gives us the IPV4 address of the device. I've fixed the codes. Thanks